# Corrupted InnoDB still won't start even after removing corrupted tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, linux

My MySQL server stopped working randomly and upon checking log files I found this:

```
190622 23:45:10 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

***

    Version: '10.0.31-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  SLE 12 SP1 package
    2019-06-22 23:45:13 7f3013fff700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139844470699776 in file trx0purge.cc line 698
    InnoDB: Failing assertion: purge_sys->iter.trx_no <= purge_sys->rseg->last_trx_no
    InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
    InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
    InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
    InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
    InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
    InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
    InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
    190622 23:45:13 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
    This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
    or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
    or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

    To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

    We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
    diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
    something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

    Server version: 10.0.31-MariaDB
    key_buffer_size=134217728
    read_buffer_size=131072
    max_used_connections=0
    max_threads=153
    thread_count=0
    It is possible that mysqld could use up to
    key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 467015 K  bytes of memory
    Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
```

So I googled a bunch to figure out how to diagnose what might have become corrupt. I did the usual `innodb_force_recovery = 3`, which was the lowest tier that would permit the service to run.

At which point I ran `mysqlcheck --all-databases -u root -p` which did, indeed, provide me with one corrupted table from a nextcloud database. I haven't used nextcloud in years so I went ahead and decided to drop the entire database by logging into mysql normally and running `DROP DATABASE nextcloud;` and it do so just fine.

Now when I run the `mysqlcheck` it lists all databases as fine:

```
mysql.column_stats                                 OK
mysql.columns_priv                                 OK
mysql.db                                           OK
mysql.event                                        OK
mysql.func                                         OK
mysql.gtid_slave_pos                               OK
mysql.help_category                                OK
mysql.help_keyword                                 OK
mysql.help_relation                                OK
mysql.help_topic                                   OK
mysql.host                                         OK
mysql.index_stats                                  OK
mysql.innodb_index_stats                           OK
mysql.innodb_table_stats                           OK
mysql.plugin                                       OK
mysql.proc                                         OK
mysql.procs_priv                                   OK
mysql.proxies_priv                                 OK
mysql.roles_mapping                                OK
mysql.servers                                      OK
mysql.table_stats                                  OK
mysql.tables_priv                                  OK
mysql.time_zone                                    OK
mysql.time_zone_leap_second                        OK
mysql.time_zone_name                               OK
mysql.time_zone_transition                         OK
mysql.time_zone_transition_type                    OK
mysql.user                                         OK
territory.points                                   OK
wordpress.wp_commentmeta                           OK
wordpress.wp_comments                              OK
wordpress.wp_links                                 OK
wordpress.wp_options                               OK
wordpress.wp_postmeta                              OK
wordpress.wp_posts                                 OK
wordpress.wp_term_relationships                    OK
wordpress.wp_term_taxonomy                         OK
wordpress.wp_termmeta                              OK
wordpress.wp_terms                                 OK
wordpress.wp_usermeta                              OK
wordpress.wp_users                                 OK
```

So I went ahead and removed the `innodb_force_recovery = 3` and attempted to restart the mysql service. Sadly it still won't run on anything less than tier 3 recovery. At this point I am somewhat lost. Where should I look next to find out what's causing the corruption still? Oh and the mysql logs remain the exact same, so no change there.

I don't particularly care if I lose the data, as the only database I care about is `territory`. Obviously I'd like to keep the data, but if my only option is to somehow start semi-fresh with mysql, then I'll do that but only if it is my last option.

Comment: You could try to dump this db (`mysqldump territory`), and load it in a different db .  If this fails, than check what error it gives. The output of mysqldump produces readable SQL.

Comment: Alright, I did this and mysql dump seems to work without any displayed errors. I also discovered that by just running `mysql_purge_threads = 0` and not `mysql_force_recovery = 3` the service seems to still start. I don't know if this is viable, though in developmental environments.

Comment: Sorry - apparently it was reading the `my.cnf` file from before i made changes. It still will only run with `mysql_force_recovery = 3` set. Is there anything indicating that the territory database is corrupt?

Comment: A good way to check is to export, and to import it. If that succeeds, than chances are that corruption is in another db.

Comment: This looks like [MDEV-15370](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15370) which only has a 10.3 fix. Maybe copy the datadir to a 10.3 instance and see if 10.3 can start with it.

Comment: from Marko, MariaDB Innodb lead: MDEV-15370 was a bug when ugprading to 10.3, caused by MDEV-12288. Actually upgrades can still fail (MDEV-15912) if a slow shutdown of the old server was not made.
Because the scenario does not involve upgrading to 10.3 or later, I am afraid that the user witnessed some kind of undo log corruption. Starting up with innodb_force_recovery=3 might allow dumping all data. If that crashes, then try innodb_force_recovery=5, but be aware that anything >3 may corrupt the database further, and therefore you should not use the database for anything else than mysqldump